# How to delete specific nodes from an XML file using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I've an xml file (Sample.xml) which has the following structure

```
    <RootElement>     
        <Child Name="FirstChild" Start="1" End="2"/>
        <Child Name="SecondChild" Start="0" End="2"/>           
        <Child Name="ThirdChild" Start="1" End="2"/>            
        <Child Name="FourthChild" Start="0" End="2"/>            
        <Child Name="FifthChild" Start="0" End="2"/>            
        <Child Name="SixthChild" Start="1" End="2"/>   
        <MatchedChilds>  
            <Child Name="FirstChild" />  
            <Child Name="SecondChild" />  
            <Child Name="ThirdChild" />  
            <Child Name="FourthChild" />  
            <Child Name="FifthChild" />  
            <Child Name="SixthChild" />   
    </MatchedChilds> 
</RootElement>
```

i need to remove  the elements "Child" if it is directly under "RootElement"

please give me a XML to LINQ approch to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        XDocument X_DOC = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Sample.xml");
        X_DOC.Root.Elements("Child").Remove();
        X_DOC.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\Sample.xml");
```

Comment: You should call `Path.Combine`.  Also, you don't need the `Where` call.

Comment: @ SLaks : Thank you..... Edited in (line no. 2) .Kindly post an example for 
                      Path.Combile

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over the nodes and remove them, like this:

```
foreach(var child in root.Elements("Child").ToArray())
    child.Remove();
```

The `Elements` call will return all direct child elements of the element you call it on; it will not return grandchildren;

You must call `ToArray` or you'll be modifying the collection as you enumerate it.